# how to deal with timeout in ROR project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timeout

I am working for a project with ruby on rails. There's one page with a list of items you can choose multiple of them and change their information at a time. But when the data are too huge and you choose too many items to get in process at a time. It will run for a few minutes long, then the page will show error message and it is caused by the server timeout...How can I let it run even for ten minutes but not timeout and return an error message?

Comment: process long tasks in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not one way to do this.

Firstly, you can look in your log to check for long sql queries, if you see some very long ones, you can try and optimize them.

You can also use gems like rails-footnotes to see the sql queries in the bottom of each page in dev environment.

If you are doing some expensive tasks, try to process them in the background with tools such as resque or delayed_jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Best user-friendly solution is to use some background tasks...

Like delayed_job, for example :

```
def my_action
  do_some_stuff
end
handle_asynchronously :my_action, :priority => 1
```

Then, your action will be done asynchronously and your server will continue to work normally.